# Meaning of 'naturally contented temperament'

Tags: sentence-meaning

I didn't understand the meaning of the highlighted sentence.

> On the whole, the happiest people seem to be those who have no
>   particular cause for being happy except the fact that they are so—a
>   good reason, no doubt. **And yet I should not choose a naturally
>   contented temperament as my first request from a fairy godmother.** It
>   would be unfortunate if I said, ' I wish to be the happiest man in
>   England' and promptly myself locked up in an asylum, a cheerful
>   lunatic who believed himself to be the Emperor of China. For all we
>   know to the contrary, the happiest man in England may be a madman, and
>   none of us would wish to change places with him. And even if the
>   always cheerful person is perfectly sane. he is without the 'splendid
>   spur' which most men need if they are to do much with their lives.

Comment: It is in their nature to be content or contented.  They have a "happy or cheerful disposition".

Comment: What is 'first request from a fairy godmother' ?

Comment: Characters in European fairy-tales are often allowed to make three wishes. The "fairy godmother" is a kind of magical creature who grants such wishes. So, being happy is not top on his list of things to wish for.

Answer (score 1):

The modifier **naturally contented** (it modifies **temperament**) consists of a past participle (**contented**) functioning adjectivally, and an adverb, **naturally**, modifying the modifier.

To be *contented* is to be satisfied or happy.

To be *naturally contented* is to be satisfied or happy as one's default state of mind; one's nature is to be contented.